# javascript promises: not understanding how to get value out of a promise

Tags: javascript, promise

I am having trouble understanding how to get a value out of a promise in javascript.

I have these functions:

```
const getProjectById = (id) => {
  return fetch(`/api/project/${id}`)
    .then((response) => response.json());
}


const getProjectNameFromId = (id) => {
  let name = 'blah';
  getProjectById(id).then((result) => {name = result.name;});
  return name;
}
```

In the browser's javascript console I have entered these functions and confirmed that when I do something like

```
let test = getProjectById("52");
```

it returns a promise, which then resolves to the expected info.

I want to call `getProjectNameFromId()` to get a project name which I can then pass to a React object as a prop.  But instead of `getProjectNameFromId()` returning the actual project name, it always returns `'blah'`.

I understand that the promise is asynchronous and that is why this is not working for me.  But I just don't get how to do this properly.

Comment: Read up on using async/await. Or update the prop in your `then()`

Comment: Oooh, thanks for the tip.  Thats was exactly the hint I needed.  I did the `ReactDOM.render()` inside of the `then()` and it worked!